# Starting Android Development with some questions

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Ok, 
So I just started learning JAVA and computer programming in general, I want to learn even more languages but I think JAVA is best for me at this moment and I have a few questions.

1. Ok, so can I code without Android Kit, I have the "Eclipse Android" and I'm not sure yet if I can use it.
2. I know that you can use JAVA to develop apps for phone, but can I design them from nothing, or I really have to use that Android Kit.
3. What else languages I should learn to be ok with Android Development.

Sorry if those are stupid questions, but I really need answers to those. They frustrate me very hard and I can't find some answers.

Comment: Is there a really good reason why you don't want/cant use Android Studio?
In my opinion it's always better to develop with an IDE.

Comment: No there's not but I find it quite hard to use it but if it's better to use their IDE I will start learning A.S.

Comment: It's what I recommend as with all tools it takes some time to master but It's the way to go

Comment: Eclipse "Android Developer Tools"  was deprecated since like 2015 June, you should not bother with it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand you question but here are a few things that might get you started.

1. First off, I would use Android studio rather than eclipse. Eclipse is bloated and slow and Android Studio has more support from Google.
2. You need to install the SDK. You can do this with the SDK manager built into the Android studio IDE.
3. You need to get familiar with XML (not that it is a real language) and gradle to get a "Hello World" example.
4. Try following a tutorial such as this. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My sugestion is to use Android Studio, desining layouts the language is XML this is really easy to learn.

To program in java you don't need the android sdk you can use intellij java or Eclipse but if you want to develop apps my sugestion is Android Studio.

You may want to learn php and sql this is not exactly for android development but you will need to learn those languages if you want to conenct to a server and the database

And just like any software Android Studio might seem a hard to use at first but with time becomes easy

Comment: I want to make games very simple with one tap or something like this only. Thx for help!

Comment: simple games android studio is fine but if you want to go full throttle on game development go for unity is the best engine i used language is C# there are great curses that you can take online in Udemy i also encourage you to learn to use blender

Comment: I try to make simple games, I don't want to go too deep in complex games. I want to do games like Flappy bird or those type of games. Also some apps, that count steps and this kind of things.

Comment: flappy bird is  harder to make in Android Studio  in Unity is much easyer must of the physics are built in

Comment: I want to make games using Tap style, nothing more. I mean, just simple games that are becoming addictive. I dont like Unity to be honest. Or "Zig Zag" game or stuff like this . Still unity?

Comment: you can try other game engine but the best one i know is unity, and yes you need a gameengine to make those games, it may be possible to do that in Android Studio but it will take alot of work